# How can I count the non-unique combinations of values in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with some legacy data that I suspect may be a little messed up. It is a many-to-many join table.

```
LIST_MEMBERSHIPS
----------------
list_id
address_id
```

I'd like to run a query that will count the occurrences of each `list_id`-`address_id` pair and show the occurrence count for each from highest to lowest number of occurrences.

I know it's got to involve `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`, right?

Comment: What is your table definition like for your LIST_MEMBERSHIPS table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select list_id, address_id, count(*) as count
from LIST_MEMBERSHIPS
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc
```

You may find it useful to add

```
having count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), list_id, address_id
from list_membership
group by list_id, address_id
order by count(*) desc
```